# Size of iPhone device token

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

What is the size of the device token generated by APNs (Apple Push Notification). I am trying to store device tokens on the server side in a mysql database, and would like to know maximum size of device tokens generated

Comment: it is 64 char in length

Comment: it is not 64 char in lenght anymore, it changes, some of them 64 some of them 108 etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You get told but it's currently 32 bytes. [Apple says the token length is variable and to not hard code it](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW14)

When you get a notification it has a header, currently 35 bytes in size. This is arranged as follows:

- **Byte 1:** Command
- **Byte 2-3:** Token length
- **Bytes 4-35:** Token

Source: http://mark.aufflick.com/files/view/talks/apns.pdf

Comment: you have said its totaly 32 bytes ...But you are mentioning Bytes 4-35...can you plz explain that ?

Comment: @NagaR I've just expanded the content a bit to explain where the numbering comes from. The number is the index in the header. So byte 1 of the token occupies byte 4 in the header, byte 2 in the token occupies byte 5 in the header... byte 32 of the token occupies byte 35 in the header.

Comment: Apple says the token length is variable and to not hard code it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW12

Answer (score 19):

[Apple Push Notification Service Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW14) very clearly says:

> "Important: APNs device tokens are of variable length. Do not hardcode their size."

Comment: I wish this question would be revisited. This is (as of now) the correct answer.

Comment: updated documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html

Answer (score 4):

According to Apple's iOS Developer Library, it's 32 bytes, as Philip said.

Here's a link to their page on "Local and Push Notification Programming," which may include other helpful information on the subject.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @QED the link is fixed

Comment: @Alastair the link is broken again

Answer (score -7):

The limit in iOS8 is reported to be 2k.  Still half of the size of GCM's 4k, but I suspect most people will have to alter their tables to handle the new iOS8 token limit.

Comment: he didn't ask about the size of the push payload, but the token itself.

Comment: GCM token can (technically) be up to 4k long as well. Practically it should be within 255 though.

Comment: I agree with James, GCM's token length can be up to 4K and the payload itself can be up to 4K.

Comment: The question was about token size, not about payload size.