# iOS Device Token example for Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I need to pass through server auth method, which needs deviceToken for registration.
But I have only simulators, and can't take tokens from them, and I want to send to server false token (like 000 000 000)
But I don't know how many digits are there in device token.
Can anyone help me out with a sample device token?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452448/size-of-iphone-device-token)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Device token is of 32 Bytes. Sample device token is provided for your reference from [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

```
740f4707 bebcf74f 9b7c25d4 8e335894 5f6aa01d a5ddb387 462c7eaf 61bb78ad
```

Comment: No it's not, it has a variable length, do not hardcode it.

Comment: @fpg1503 This question asked for an example so is the answer containing.

Comment: I misexpressed myself, do not hardcode its length (32 bytes)

Comment: Yes I agree with that, hardcoding in not a great practice, but the answer is just an example of device token

Answer (score 3):

[Apple Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW14)
clearly states:

> "Important: APNs device tokens are of variable length. Do not hardcode their size."

The may currently have 32 bytes but hardcoding that will make your app break in the future!

Answer (score 1):

It is 32 bytes. Written in hexadecimal they will take 64 digits.

You can check this page for more detail :

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html

Comment: 32 bytes is not 32 digits. If written in hexadecimal it is 64 digits.

Comment: @jbx How do we convert it from hexadecimal 64 digits to 32-byte 32 digits?

Comment: What do you mean? 1 byte needs 2 hex digits, from 00 to FF. You cannot represent 1 byte with 1 hex digit. So 32 bytes need 64 digits.