# Invalid parameter: Token Reason: iOS device tokens must be no more than 400 hexadecimal characters

Tags: java, ios, spring-boot, amazon-sns

I am trying to create platform endpoint in `amazon sns` from the console.
Below is the device token which I received from `FCM/APNs`:

`fUG5dIcN_pA:APA91bEciRwWuvTIezAKcJ5y1xz5z6BygE3YJkywdCGCFJD93NTfjARwPRommwgsfvVo2iH_qZWT7D2Lxnc69uanato1UUq-nLl5R1L0qF4exT7zjM9Wdy9Evs6h-EOBtIVv7Vv8bPE1`

I am getting an error: **iOS device tokens must be no more than 400 hexadecimal characters**.looks like APNs has sent token in string format and Amazon is expecting it in hexadecimal chars.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I think you are getting the wrong device token. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821090/ios-device-token-example-for-push-notifications

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

Try the below code in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`:

```
let deviceToken = deviceToken.map {String(format:"%02.2hhx",$0)}.joined()
print(deviceToken)
```

And Paste the device token in amazon SNS console, it will work.

Comment: How to write this in objective c ? I got error: `Property 'map' not found on object of type 'NSData *'`

Answer (score 1):

For objective-c you can use this:

```
NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

NSLog(@"The generated device token string is : %@",deviceTokenString);
```

Comment: thanks, but I have converted the result back to `NSData` format, as the function `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken` returns `[RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:data];`

and I got the same error: `Invalid parameter: Token Reason: iOS device tokens must be no more than 400 hexadecimal characters`

Comment: Did you try the solution I gave or not?

Comment: Yes, I did, but how to pass the result without have to convert it to `NSData ` ? if I try to pass it as is, I got error: `-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: You tried this `NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`? to convert to NSData?

Comment: Yes, I tried `NSData *data = [deviceTokenString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: Did you check this thread? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=572827
 Since you need it as NSData not NSString, and it wouldn't make sense to convert twice the token

Comment: I saw similar discussions, what they do is create the SNS endpoint inside `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` but I am trying to create it server side to avoid using SNS apis within the app it self

Comment: Thanks DionizB, I am trying to avoid store SNS credentials within the app for the sake of security

Comment: What exactly your code do? maybe I can re-wrote in using Ruby

Comment: It removes occurrences  of `<`, `>` and ` ` (empty space), from the token, maybe if you try to remove them on your side it might work

Comment: How to do same for react native?

Answer (score 0):

**I experienced this error after iOS 13**. Since iOS 13 the token provided via the app delegate changed and if the delegate code is not updated for iOS 13 then an invalid token will be sent up.

Check this stack overflow link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839723/does-ios-13-has-new-way-of-getting-device-notification-token) for an example of how to update.