# Adapter Apns does not support xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx token's device

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, laravel-5.3

I am using [this](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification) to send push notifications in `Laravel` to an `iOS` application. It works fine on token with 64 characters length, but it throws this error with token of length of 54 characters.

I am sending the push with the following code:

```
$payload = PushNotification::Message($message, array(
                        'badge' => 1,
                        'sound' => 'default',
                    ));

                    PushNotification::app('appNameIOS')
                        ->to($device_token)
                        ->send($payload);
```

I am trying to catch the exception like this:

```
catch (Exception $ex){
//do something
}
```

And this:

```
catch (PushException $ex) {
//do something
}
```

But it doesn't catch exception and throws me this error:

> Adapter Apns does not support xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx token's device

How do I validate the token before sending a push?

Comment: see this once https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification/issues/96

Comment: Try to check if device token is valid before sending the notification..

Comment: yeah, I have seen this and this hard codes checks the length of the token to be 64 and that is not right as the length can be variable. look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452448/size-of-iphone-device-token

Comment: @AsfandyarKhan yeah I know that, but how am I gonna do that? That is the primary question.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the notification Check if it is a valid token.

```
if( ctype_xdigit($device_token) && 64 == strlen($device_token)){
      $msgPush = 'There are new actity';
      $payload = PushNotification::Message($message, array(
                    'badge' => 1,
                    'sound' => 'default',
                ));

                PushNotification::app('appNameIOS')
                    ->to($device_token)
                    ->send($payload);
}
```

Comment: This hard codes checks the length of the token to be 64 and that is not right as the length can be variable. look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452448/size-of-iphone-device-token

Comment: check if the device token is not properly formatted or not.